# PHP sort locations by distance, returns nothing

Tags: php

I'm testing some code to sort locations by distance from a specific point, got some code and it's returning nothing...

I'm entering this URL

```
http://localhost:8888/jsontest.php?category=all&long=-2.837275&lat=51.967825
```

to enter my variables for the lat and long as my current location, and here is the query:

```
mysql_query("SELECT *,  ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('$lat') ) *  cos( radians( lat ) ) *  cos( radians( long ) -  radians('$lon') ) +  sin( radians('$lat') ) *  sin( radians( lat ) ) ) )  AS distance FROM LISTINGS ORDER BY distance ASC");
```

Getting variables from URL:

```
$lon = $_GET["long"];
$lat = $_GET["lat"];
```

Database table name is listings, lat and long columns are called lat and long, can anyone help!

Thanks.

Comment: Take PHP out of the equation. Make an SQL query that works like you need to first, then modify it for use with variables.

Comment: I've tried that, no luck! The variables work perfectly, i've echoed them, so should be fine! Thanks.

Comment: What is your query whithout PHP variables?

Comment: Just replaced, $lat, with 51.967825 and long with -2.837275.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to be doing Geospatial Calculations manually. It gets complicated when you need Near , Radios, Box , Polygon or Relative Distance. .... MySQL has [Spatial Extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html) or better sill use [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing) what you have is the same thing as

```
db.places.find( { loc : { $near : [-2.837275,51.967825] } } )
```

The above query finds the closest points to `(-2.837275,51.967825)` and returns them **sorted** by distance (there is no need for an additional **sort** parameter).

Comment: So, how would i implement this, giving what i have said above, sorry for being a noob!

Comment: Click on the links in my answer .. it would take you there .. i personally prefer the MongoDB options .. really simple

Comment: Don't really understand how to implement it, ie with the query etc. Sorry!

Comment: Do you know how to use MongoDB ?